# use PKCS#8 private key in C# to sign data

Tags: c#, cryptography, pkcs#8

The Service we access for authentication, returns PKCS#8, encoded private and public key separately as bytes. I need to use this private key and sign the payload, which will be verified at server side. I have exhausted the RSACryptoServiceProvider and RsaSecurityToken, which does not import private key alone.